# django-filebrowser 'Error finding Upload-Folder'

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

I have:

- Django 1.8.2
- django-grappelli 2.7.3
- django-filebrowser 3.6.4
- django-tinymce 2.4.0

In `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
    'django.contrib.admin',
```

In `urlpatterns`:

```
from filebrowser.sites import site

urlpatterns = patterns[
   url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),
   url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
   url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Which seems to work correctly.

My `MEDIA_ROOT` is set to `'D:\\sites\\my_site\\public_html\\media\\'`.

I have `FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = 'D:\\sites\\my_site\\public_html\\media\\'` set also in my settings, but still getting an error on browsing `http://localhost:8000/admin/filebrowser/browse/`:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/filebrowser/browse/

Error finding Upload-Folder (site.storage.location + site.directory). Maybe it does not exist?
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The thing is `DIRECTORY` is set in filebrowser.settings by default to `uploads/`. So just did

```
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = ''
DIRECTORY = ''
```

in my settings and now it works using `MEDIA_ROOT` as I was expexting.

Or one just can create `uploads` directory inside `MEDIA_ROOT` to make it work.

Comment: Thank you. It was pain to set this thing. For me now (django-filebrowser==3.11.1) it works with FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY= setting only (="" or =".", but not ="/"), I don't need DIRECTORY=.. But because MEDIA_ROOT is used for uploads from FileField's inside the admin, it is better for me to create a separate directory like FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY="dashboard_uploads/".

Comment: I think, the `DIRECTORY` setting has no effect. And in my case, it was that `media` directory wasn't created at all, and I had to add it.